# Reading cookie information from a WebSocket request

Tags: node.js, cookies, websocket, connect

I'm using Node.js and WebSocket-Node ([WebSocket-Node](https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node)) to create a WebService. I need to access the cookie or session information from the web server to tie the WebSocket connection to a user id. I know that the cookie information is being send via req.cookies, but I'm not familiar with the syntax to access the "connect.sid" cookie.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the library code (around line 200):

https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node/blob/master/lib/WebSocketRequest.js

it seems that cookies is an array of object with "name" and "value" properties

So you can have a function like this (*not tested*):

```
function getSidFromCookies(cookies) {
     var filtered = cookies.filter(function(obj) {
         return obj.name == 'connect.sid';
     });
     return filtered.length > 0 ? filtered[0].value : null;
}
```

then you can just do:

```
var connectSid = getSidFromCookies(req.cookies);
```

**connectSid** will either be the cookie value or null

Comment: sorry, small typo, i'll update the answer code =D (the function just needs to return filtered[0].value instead of the object itself)